# Send email to all contacts in Outlook address book when a new email received (VB)

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I want to write a VBA script that when Outlook receive a new email from a specific email address , the VBA script has to detect that and resend the new received email to all contacts in the address book .

For now i was able to send an email to all contacts in address book :

```
Sub SendEmails()
Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Dim Contact As Object
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olApp = Outlook.Application

For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
    Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With objMail
        .Subject = "Subject of the received email"
        .Body = "Body of the received email"
        .To = Contact.Email1Address
        .Send
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

but how to use this script so it called when a new email received from a specific email address.

i tried  to put this in ThisOulookSeassion to check for new message event so i could call my above code within it :

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
MsgBox "New mail"
End Sub
```

but it didn't work.

Also i tried this (i put it in ThisOulookSeassion too) :

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
' default local Inbox
Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
 End Sub
  Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

 On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
 If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
   Set Msg = item 
   ' ******************
   ' and placing my code here.
   ' ******************
   End If
 ProgramExit: 
  Exit Sub
 ErrorHandler: 
   MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
  Resume ProgramExit 
 End Sub
```

but when i click run it ask me to create  new macro and don't run the code.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: *All* contacts? Are you creating a virus?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko haha , no i just want to send daily news to subscribers . that's it :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a rule in Outlook. Then you can assign an existing VBA macro to run when the rule is run. Typically a VBA sub should like the following one:

```
 Sub SendEmails(mail as MailItem)
   Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
   Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
   Dim objMail as MailItem
   Dim Contact As Object

   For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
      Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      With objMail
        .Subject = mail.Subject
        .Body = "Body Text"
        .To = Contact.Email1Address
        .Send
      End With
   Next
 End Sub
```

Also you may consider adding recipients to the Recipients collection and set their [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703(v=office.15).aspx) to the *olBCC* value. Thus, each of them will recieve a separate email and you have to submit only a single mail item.

Comment: thanks @Eugene it's a great solution but there is one issue , how can i get the subject and the title of the received email and use it inside the "SendEmails" macro instead of "Test Message" and "Body Text" ?

Also talking about sending one email by put contacts in bbc instead of sending to everyone separately . the problem of this solution is it most email spam filters consider the email as a spam .

Comment: You have already got an instance of the MailItem class passed as a parameter. Just get the required properties there. See the souce code changed.